# Link to the wiki to the sidebar?

Tags: feature-request

The wiki is not easy to find: if you search for "wiki" you find a lot of links to Wikipedia. And you need to know to look for it in the first place. If we link to it to the sidebar, we can give people a fighting chance of finding it.

Comment: Do you mean Community Wiki answers generally or one specific post?   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1&submit=search finds them all

Comment: That ":1" trick is one I did not know.